# If a curious solo alien arrived at Earth, what would the most likely human response be?

Tags: aliens, firstcontact

Revised question:

Suppose a singular alien in his small starship (probably around 200m long) exits warp just outside of Earth's SOI. He, perceiving Earth to be a colony somehow missing from his star map (which happens sometimes), requests identification and permission to refuel. This and the warp distortions give humans astronomers (and whoever else may be listening) a signal that something unusual is out there.

To avoid a multi-portion question, I'll simply ask, What would the astronomers and defense agencies most likely response be if my alien stayed in high orbit for the time being? And, if I may extend this a bit, how would the human reaction vary as my alien came closer to Earth?

I'll accept speculative answers or references to things to research.

Comment: You have forgotten to mention many details, for example, how big or small is he? (flea, microbe, mouse, human, whale or a mountain?) What does he look like? (angel, devil, a poodle of water, ...) and so on, so on. When you'll decide what is he, you'll find answers for most of your questions. For example there was a story about a black UFO guy that comes to USA in 50ties. He is simply thrown to prison by the police for his improper behaviour.

Comment: Or there were stories about cats that came to Earth and they found here a civilization of cats, served by clever monkeys. The same was about cars.

Comment: I can imagine many kinds of reactions, such as anything from shooting him with a cellphone to shooting him with a shotgun. There's all kinds of people living out in rural areas. So how this plays out strongly depends on what kind of person/people your alien first encounters.

Comment: It also depends on how stealthy his spacecraft is.  Interpersonal reactions would be very separate from near-earth monitoring agencies' reactions.

Comment: *"How soon would police [...] arrive on scene?"* That depends on the place. In most places in Europe, police would be on scene within ten minutes of a call to 112. But if the call was placed from somewhere in northern Finland or Sweden, or on some small Greek island in the Aegean, it may take much longer.

Comment: @jdunlop Not stealthy at all. His orbital ship is quite large, perhaps comparable to the ISS. He would land with a SSTO of some sort. Neither of which are intended for stealth. I imagine human scientists could detect gravitational distortions (caused by his ship's warp drive). That would give earthlings a heads-up.

Comment: If his "orbital ship" arrived in orbit with normal "strolling down the hall to the shuttle" latency, every major defense organization on earth and some commercial outfits would know the _exact_ location his shuttle lands.

Comment: @jdunlop I then ought to research how air traffic authorities react to unidentified aircraft in their airspace, right?

Comment: Where do they land? There's a very big difference between them landing in New York City and them landing in Pyongyang...

Comment: As @AlexP said, this is completely unanswerable without knowing *where* the alien landed.  To pick another extreme, some of the outback farms in Australia are huge, so no locals would be in the vicinity for hours even if they saw the lander descending - OTOH you would need to look at both US and Australian radar facilities in Australia compared to the lander's descent path to see whether the military detected him.  VTC without more details.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming he doesn't want immediate notoriety then he'd pick an island somewhere without an airport. If it's an independent one then there will be all sorts of negotiations and bribes necessary before locals would give access to international teams. Probably at least a day.

He'd be all over Social Media within hours though.

Hard to say what the locals would do, they might kill him or might call the police or other leaders all of whom would be trying to decide if it's a business opportunity.

Comment: i doubt that "over Social Media within hours". would you believe a tik tok with an alien was real, or would you think it was cgi?

Comment: Regardless of whether or not anyone *believes* the Internet, the alien will certainly be all over the Miscellaneous Island Nation's subreddits and image boards within hours.

Comment: @ths I never said it would be believed, but anything happening on a small island is the drama of the moment to almost everyone